# Mass Update Vendor Names in QuickBooks

Tags: excel, import, export, quickbooks

We are building an application to import data into QuickBooks for a company that has been manually entering the data from their own accounting program.

One issue we have run into is that the Vendor name in QuickBooks is not always exactly the same as the Vendor name in their accounting program.

I am looking for a way to pull a list of the Vendors from QuickBooks and compare it with a list from their accounting program remove all the ones that are the same and present the ons that are different to the user to match. Then update QuickBooks with the corrected names.

I found a way to manually update the vendor names using the add/edit multiple List entries screen in QuickBooks, but that would mean a lot of copy/pasting for the users and could introduce errors.

Something that could be implemented in C# would be most preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the QuickBooks SDK to access this information, but you would need to know programming and I think it would probably be overkill for your situation. I would suggest looking at some third party software for importing/exporting data into QuickBooks. I use Transaction Pro Importer from BayStateConsulting (http://www.baystateconsulting.com/) for a lot of my customer's who need basic import/export features.